# posting array of input boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following

```
 @foreach (var language in Model.LanguagesList)
 {
       <input type="text" name="txtLanguage[@language.Value]" value="@language.Text" />
 }
```

I used to use something like this years ago whilst writing php and it was easy to get the values when posted back.

I need the key and the value but can't seem to find a way to get them.

the only bit of code that I have been able to find is this

```
        NameValueCollection nv = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request["txtLanguage"]);
        foreach (string key in nv)
        {
            //var key = key;
            var value = nv[key];
        }
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Do you post is as GET or POST? Can you provide more code around the example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all this wrapped in a form and specified action and controller correctly, you would need to iterate and post **Text** and **Value** separately following way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName", 
                   "YourControllerName", 
                   FormMethod.Post))
{
   .................................
   .................................
   @for(int i=0 i< Model.LanguagesList.Count; i++)
   {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> Model.LanguagesList[i].Text)
       @Html.HiddenFor(x=> Model.LanguagesList[i].Value)
   }
   .................................
   .................................
   <input type="submit" Value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that but I need to get the values after the form is posted not to generate the form

Comment: they will be posted back when the form is submitted, can you show your controller action code, how you set it up?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to comment on Eshan's reply, you can use below in view ( as eshan explained)

```
      @for(int i=0 i< Model.LanguagesList.Count; i++)
   {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> Model.LanguagesList[i].Text)
       @Html.HiddenFor(x=> Model.LanguagesList[i].Value)
   }
```

You can access field's value using FormCollection in Model or Controller

```
public ActionResult MyController(FormCollection collection)
        {
```

......
    }